# How to overcome proxy error in ASP.Net with React.js project?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I'm new to ASP.NET. I created an ASP.Net with React.js project. And it has a default simple project called `/weatherforecast`. I followed the instructions given in the official [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022). But couldn't solve the proxy error:
[image: terminal-output]

`launchSettings.json`:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001"
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7161;http://localhost:5001"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55922",
      "sslPort": 44352
    }
  }
}
```

`vite.config.js`:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url';

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import plugin from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import child_process from 'child_process';

const baseFolder =
    process.env.APPDATA !== undefined && process.env.APPDATA !== ''
        ? `${process.env.APPDATA}/ASP.NET/https`
        : `${process.env.HOME}/.aspnet/https`;

const certificateArg = process.argv.map(arg => arg.match(/--name=(?<value>.+)/i)).filter(Boolean)[0];
const certificateName = certificateArg ? certificateArg.groups.value : "reactapp1.client";

if (!certificateName) {
    console.error('Invalid certificate name. Run this script in the context of an npm/yarn script or pass --name=<<app>> explicitly.')
    process.exit(-1);
}

const certFilePath = path.join(baseFolder, `${certificateName}.pem`);
const keyFilePath = path.join(baseFolder, `${certificateName}.key`);

if (!fs.existsSync(certFilePath) || !fs.existsSync(keyFilePath)) {
    if (0 !== child_process.spawnSync('dotnet', [
        'dev-certs',
        'https',
        '--export-path',
        certFilePath,
        '--format',
        'Pem',
        '--no-password',
    ], { stdio: 'inherit', }).status) {
        throw new Error("Could not create certificate.");
    }
}

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [plugin()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    },
    server: {
        proxy: {
            '^/weatherforecast': {
                target: 'https://localhost:7161/',
                secure: false
            }
        },
        port: 5173,
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(keyFilePath),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(certFilePath),
        }
    }
})
```

As I observed, the applicationUrl in `launchSetttings.json` matches the server proxy in `vite.config.js`.

Project Structure:

[image]